# Mongodb lookup alternative for join two collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mLab.com as my MongoBb provider but like other services the MongoBb version is 3.0.x and doesn't support $lookup.
I need to do a join between two of my collections.
Is there any alternative for $lookup in Mongodb versions before version 3.2 ?

Comment: What do your collections look like and what is the query that you're trying to do?

Comment: You can definitely do this on client side using any programming language. Loop through cursor in one collection and fetch related documents from other.